# how to cast char * as doubles?

Tags: c++

i have a struct with x,y,z as the type double. I'm trying to split the lines by spaces and then put the values of that array into my structure but it fails to work, can someone tell me what to do?

```
#include "_externals.h"
#include <vector>

typedef struct
{
    double X, Y, Z;
} p;

p vert = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

int main()
{
    char *path = "C:\\data.poi";    

    ifstream inf(path);
    ifstream::pos_type size;
    inf.seekg(0, inf.end);
    size = inf.tellg();

    double x, y, z;
    char *data;

    data = new char[size];
    inf.seekg(inf.beg);
    inf.read(data, size);
    inf.seekg(inf.beg);

    char** p = &data;
    char *line = *p;    

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(data); ++i)
    {
        const char *verts = strtok(line, " ");

        //this isnt working
        vert.X = verts[0];
        vert.Y = verts[1];
        vert.Z = verts[2];

        ++*line;
    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: Is your data file 3-doubles per line each separated by whitespace? Just curious.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "C" if you're using `ifstream` and `#include <vector>`?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot (meaningfully) **cast** a `char*` as a `double`, but you can extract from a *stream* into a `double`.

Since you are splitting the input line on spaces, the typical idiom is like this... for each line in the file, create an [**`istringstream`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) object and use this to populate your structure.

If [`operator >>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected) the target value is left unmodified and [**`failbit`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) is set.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct coords
{
    double X, Y, Z;
};


int main()
{
    std::ifstream inf("data.poi");
    std::vector<coords> verts;
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inf, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        coords coord;

        if (iss >> coord.X >> coord.Y >> coord.Z)
        {
            verts.push_back(coord);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Could not process " << line << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 nice solution. I'm curious: since anything after the first three valid doubles on a given line are discarded, can you instead move your current `if` clause extraction to be the primary extraction from `inf`, forego the `istringstream` entirely,  and immediately after `verts.push_back()` do a `std::getline(inf, junk)` to eat/throw-away the remainder of the line ? (since its being ignored anyway?). just wondering.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'm not sure that would work (it would certain make it harder to report "invalid" lines). Were this my own code, I would probably extract an istream `operator` that would allow `if (iss >> coord)` but I think the example I've provided is sufficient to answer the question as asked. How the OP chooses to use it is their own concern. :)

Comment: It most certainly exceeds sufficient. I was just curious. I can never remember if a successful extraction immediately followed by newline/whitespace consumes the newline/whitespace, which is the only place I can see it causing problems. Again, very well presented solution. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The same way you would do it for an integer with atoi.

For conversion from char* to double, simply use :

> atof

[atof example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/)
.

Comment: Or `strtod()`...the error handling is better with `strtod()`.